# php Regular Expression return specific string

Tags: php, regex

Let us say, I want to return a name:

```
$re = "/(name is )[a-z- ]*( )/i";
$str = "My name is John ";

preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name is John 
    [1] => name is 
    [2] =>  
)
```

Well, let's see this:

```
$string = "My name is John and I like Ice-cream";
$pattern = "My name is $1 and I like $2";
```

With this I get:
Array

```
(
    [0] => name is John and I like Ice-cream 
    [1] => name is 
    [2] =>  and I like 
    [3] =>  
)
```

which is more or less the same string I passed.

What I am looking for is to compare and extract the variables so that I could use them as variable `$1` and `$2` or anything like this works.

Or **maybe** a method that returns an associate array or those items like:

```
Array("1" => "John" , "2" => "Ice-cream")
```

Any workaround or ideas are highly appreciated as long as they work in the way I asked above.

Comment: You didn't put a capturing group around the name. If you did your result array would provide enough information from which you could derive the array you want.

Comment: @Marty, what about the case with multiple items? Any code to share?

Comment: You could simply make more than 1 capturing group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = 'My name is John and I like Ice-cream';
$re = '/My name is (\S+) and I like (\S+)/';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => My name is John and I like Ice-cream
    [1] => John
    [2] => Ice-cream
)
```

`\\S` matches non-whitespace.

Change it to `.` to match anything, which will work as far as the other strings in the pattern ("My name is " and " I like ") are fixed.

Comment: You don't need to escape the `\` in your regex. And this will fail if a name contains whitespace or if the think you like does.

Comment: Awesome. I guess I can take the boat from here.

Comment: @arjan Added a some text concerning the whitespace issue. However, the thing about escaping I do not understand.

Comment: Umm, @Arjan, `this will fail if a name contains whitespace` yes that's true. But, is there a way to overcome?

Comment: @syck You are escaping the ``\`` in ``\S`` with another ``\``, but that's not necessary since the string is in single quotes. In php there is a difference between single quotes and double quotes. With single quotes the text is taken literally but with double quotes you can use the ``\`` to get some special behavior (like `\n` to add a newline) and variable replacement.

Comment: @syck Concerning the whitespace, I would simply use ``.*`` or ``.+`` to match any characters.

Comment: @arjan I know, but I always use `\\` as it works with single quotes as well as with double quotes.

Comment: See the last sentence in the answer and my comment above @ the whitespace issue.

Comment: @syck: even with double quotes you don't need to escape the slash here, it's not Java.

Comment: @syck: No, it's totally false. (and since PHP4 when `preg_` functions was added to the language). https://3v4l.org/48nUG (test) http://doc.php.net/archives/php4/ (documentation)

Comment: @syck: The only thing you need to take care with double quoted string and patterns are backreferences (because for example `"\101"` is seen as the octal notation of the character `A`).

Comment: Okay, I am convinced... almost =) `echo '\\\\ ';` still echoes only `\\ ` and `echo '<backslash>'` gives obviously a syntax error. `preg_match('/\/', 'abc\def');` and `preg_match('/[\]/', 'abc\def');` also wont work. So using non-escaped backslashes is sometimes convenient, but not reliable. (Sorry that I had to replace the result of the echo above because SO uses the backslash to escape backticks.)

Comment: Yes, but in these case, the situation is different. The backslash is the escape character for the pattern and for the string. With a single quoted string, its only goal is to escape a literal single quote (to say that it isn't the end of the string), and to figure a literal backslash. If you write: `echo '\d';` you obtain `\d`, if you write `echo '\\d';` same result. In a pattern the backslash is an escape character too for special regex characters `. * + ? ( ) { [ | \ ^ $` outside character classes, the pattern delimiter, and in some situations in a character class to figure a literal.

Comment: Other backslashes in patterns are escape sequences and have a special meaning like `\d` `\s` `\g{1}` etc. But your two last examples are not pertinent, because in the first, the backslash escape the delimiter, and in the second it escape the closing square bracket in the character class. Putting always double backslashes is not more reliable, it's more near a syntax error that is ignored in the most of the situations, it doesn't replace the understanding. To have a good idea of what happens with backslashes in a pattern, write your pattern in a NOWDOC string.

Answer (score 1):

Not so clean but might be helpful...

```
$string = "My name is John Cena and I like Ice-cream";
$pattern = "My name is $ and I like $";
print_r(getArray($string, $pattern));

function getArray($input, $pattern){

    $delimiter = rand();
    while (strpos($input,$delimiter) !== false) {
        $delimiter++;
    }

    $exps = explode("$",$pattern);
    foreach($exps as $exp){
        $input = str_replace($exp,",", $input);
    }

    $responses = explode(",", $input);
    array_shift($responses);
    return $responses;

}
```

It returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Cena
    [1] => Ice-cream
)
```